# Can I install Ubuntu on a USB stick when running it in a virtual machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

Can I create (for example) an Ubuntu virtual machine, plug in my USB stick and then install Ubuntu on the USB stick from the Ubuntu running in the virtual machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can make the bootable Ubuntu on USB from Ubuntu on Virtual Box.

In the VirtualBox menu select your flash drive from the USB devices, now the virtual Ubuntu detects and mounts the USB flash drive. Now go to  System → Administration → Startup Disk Creator.

[image]

Thats it!

### Installing onto the USB

I think it can be done, I tried it.

[image]

Selected my 8 GB pendrive and configured it to **EXt3/Journal file system** where flash drive is usually **fat32**, ext filesystem is usually recommend by the Ubuntu site.

[image]

and click **Install Now**.

A half hour passed and the progress bar reached 60% but it was my bad. The power was gone and the system shut down.

I can't do the same and confirm the procedure for you but I hope my experience helps you. This is enough to say that it works.

Comment: When you create startup Ubuntu usb, you can choose option to store permanent information on the USB. Does that option suffice?